# Does Android support lock-down to a fully replaced interface?

Tags: android

**What For?** This question is about how to take a peice of Android hardware and OS and turn it into an interface. It would be our own hardware, never leave the building, and run any program we create. **Why?** The Android has built in battery backup, theft detection (GPS), and an elegant touch screen, and a familiar programming interface.

**What I want:**

1. Can I require that no matter what is pressed on the screen, the user never leaves my app?

   Are there **instructions** to do this, is it **officially supported**, **or would I have to start hacking away**? (using a system-level interface, removing voice activation (when a user holds down the Search button), disable auto updates, etc)

   Ideally, I want to just write a single app that replaces the whole interface, and I want a way to hook the app in, without a bunch of extra work (rooting the phone and manually removing certain built-in apps).
2. I would also want to lock the USB into a "Charge-only" mode, to prevent mounting of the file system without my app's approval. I am not concerned about a really determined guy who opens up the device and mounts the internal storage unit's filesystem.
3. In the event of a crash, I would like to have a second app that decides whether or not to restart the first app.

Obviously, I don't want the phone to become unusable, even if it is just spare hardware.

Comment: not with stock firmware.  You would have to write custom firmware.  I don't believe that this is officially supported.

Comment: I sincerely hope it's impossible

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn, Note that this is an event when I have the hardware and am willing to use a command-line interface of a root-ed phone. In this case, I don't think it is that important it be impossible.

Comment: Followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592178/android-system-tools-display-system-level-alerts

Answer (score 2):

This is not achievable by simply writing an app. You will certainly need to do some customization on the ROM. I don't know of any official instructions to support this. You seem to have the right idea though. Removing unnecessary apps and replacing the home screen with your app should get you pretty far already. Depending on the ROM, you may also have to remove the system tray as well. Making it charge only should be easy with the right ROM as well. If all this isn't in one place, you'll have to cook your own.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

You can implement your application to receive home screen Intents, so that when the device turns on, or you hit the home key, it gets the Intent. However, then you have the stock home screen and your application registered for those Intents, and the user of the device gets to decide which of these will be the default handler.

For your third point, app crashes are handled by the OS in modern versions of Android. This was possible in older versions, I believe, but not anymore.

That's the best you can do with stock Android. If you want to do more than that, you've got to modify the system itself. You also cannot control/restrict access to the USB port in the manner you describe without modifying the kernel.

Comment: I like the custom Home Screen idea! I was not aware that was possible.

Comment: Not a common practice, but it can be effective in some use cases (such as yours, methinks).

Comment: I expect this will solve the crash question, because the crashes I believe will only do one of three things: 1. Bring you back to the home screen, 2. Report the error by launching a market-related app (which I plan to uninstall), or 3. Restart the app.

Comment: I *believe* this is true (either (1) or (2) I think), but I have not tested it. It's your most viable path forward without modifying the kernel itself, so absolutely worth a try.

Comment: I've seen it do 3 in the past. I think it only does this if you are a few activities beyond the first activity. It does not restart the activity that failed, as that is liable to cause an endless loop. I do not know for sure the logic on this.

Answer (score 1):

> I am assuming that an Android can operate under Wi-Fi only internet access, in the event I decline to pay a wireless subscription. (that of course means no phone service)

In general the answer is yes. Some devices manufacturers / carriers make it easier than others. For instance it may try to auto connect you to the phone registration system at boot, even though it will always fail. It may not quit trying. So you'd have to cancel it each time the phone boots.

> Can I require that no matter what is pressed on the screen, the user never leaves my app?

No, thankfully.

> Are there instructions to do this, is it officially supported, or would I have to start hacking away?

It is not supported, and hopefully is 100% impossible on all devices that have made their way to consumers hands. Otherwise we have big problems.

> I am thinking that if a phone was "root-ed", then things like the voice activation app could be uninstalled, and the home screen could be replaced.

The device does not need to be rooted to install a replacement home screen and set it to be used as the default. To remove things that are installed as system level applications (which voice search likely is) it would need to be rooted though.

Even if you manage to get rid of the voice search as a possible means to get out of your app. The user would still be able to longpress home and select a different application out of the list of recently launched...

If you want to disable all of the possible ways that a user could leave your application you would almost certainly have to modify the firmware to allow for this. And then your application would only work correctly on devices that are running your own version of the OS.

Comment: **Holding the home button** would only show recently used apps, and theoretically, my app is the only one that is recently used. :) **disable all possible ways to leave**, I was just wondering what other avenues could be used that I have not addressed? I am aware I might not be able to get all of them, but just wondering what could be done within reason, and what could not, and what ways there are to begin with.

Comment: That is true. I was thinking this device was still going to be used for other things, but just would be locked down while using yours. I would guess that you might actually be able to make a copy of the OS that contains no apps other than yours...What SDK version are you targeting? 3.0+ the bottom bar is going to allow the user access to "Settings" which would take them out of your app =/

Comment: Point number 3 is [handled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9590851/463304#comment12164687_9591107).

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented an application, which had similar requirements as of you, you can read my blog post here [Android auto-updating homescreen application](http://arnab.ch/blog/2012/01/android-auto-updating-homescreen-application/). Below are answers to some of your questions:

> Can I require that no matter what is pressed on the screen, the user never leaves my app?
>
> Are there instructions to do this, is it officially supported, or would I have to start >hacking away? (using a system-level interface, removing voice activation (when a user holds >down the Search button), disable auto updates, etc)
>
> Ideally, I want to just write a single app that replaces the whole interface, and I want a >way to hook the app in, without a bunch of extra work (rooting the phone and manually >removing built specific built-in apps).

As far as I know there are two ways of doing this, one is using a Homescreen application and the other is using "system alert window", and I think you're familiar with both the options.

> I would also want to lock the USB into a "Charge-only" mode, to prevent mounting of the >file system without my app's approval. I am not concerned about a really determined guy who >opens up the device and mounts the internal storage unit's filesystem.

I am not sure whether this is even possible, but you can fiddle around with low-level Linux commands if you have a rooted phone with busybox installed. Sorry, for not being much of a help here.

> In the event of a crash, I would like to have a second app that decides whether or not to >restart the first app

This is possible I believe, for example if you take a look at the existing android "crash report" tools such as [Acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/), there you'll see examples of handling crashes, what you need to do is handle the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` (these two methods are your friends `Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` and `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler eh)`). Once the handler is set from there you can decide what to do (be sure not to silently handle the exception, you must let it through so that Android can do the necessary cleanups). Now if your app is the default Homescreen, then in the event of a crash Android will automatically restart the app for you. If it's not the Homescreen application, then you can fire an Intent to restart your app when the crash happens.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In theory though, if you were using a system-level dialog, then the user would not be able to see the option to leave charge-only mode.

Comment: That's correct! in that case HomeScreen app seems to be a better option than using system-level dialog. On a side note, I am curious to know whether you're controlling the USB charging mode programmatically, as far as I know there's no API available.

Comment: ***"in that case HomeScreen app seems to be a better option"***, Hold on a moment, I **don't want the user to leave charge only mode**, Given that extra bit of information, are you now with me that the reverse would be true? (system-level being better option than home screen) ***"controlling the USB charging mode programmatically"***, not really, I can just go into the settings and set it to charge only manually. I'm just trying to make sure I can lock that option back out when I'm done (system-level dialog might work). I don't want anyone else to inject code into the phone.